# Configure Grub for Arch Linux ZFS

Tags: arch-linux, grub, zfs

Does anybody know how to configure Grub in such a way it can mount an Arch Linux installed on a ZFS system?

I have `/dev/sda1` (boot partition) and `/dev/sda2` (root partition). The ZFS system has one zpool main which has the following data containers:

```
main/root mountpoint=none
main/root/default mountpoint=legacy
main/home mountpoint=legacy
```

I also added ZFS to the `mkinitcpio.conf`.

When I try to boot the system it always says that it could not mount the
the root partition.

Do I have to change the Grub config? Honestly, I also do not care too much about Grub. If `syslinux` can do this I would switch.

EDIT:

The error which I get on boot is:

```
starting version 238
no pools available to import
ERROR: Failed to mount the real root device.
Bailing out, you are on your own. Good luck.
```

Comment: Did you try the instructions at this link? [GRUB-compatible pool creation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS#GRUB-compatible_pool_creation)

Comment: I haven't done that, but from what I can understand this is only necessary if /boot resides on zfs. I have put boot on an extra ext4 partition. I will however try it.

Comment: Just tried it. It does not work too.

Comment: If you haven't already found this post, maybe something there will help. It sounds similar to your problem. [Installing on ZFS root: "ZFS: cannot find bootfs" on boot](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174720)

Comment: Just tried the suggestions by the post, which did not work. But to be honest I do not understand the cache file. It is placed under /etc/zfs/zpool.cache, which is however only accessable after the root partition was mounted. So how can it help to mount the root partition?

Answer (score 0):

Given a root volume in a **dataset** `/ROOT/archlinux` on a **zpool** `mypool` and boot files inside the dataset at `/boot` the following commands entered into Grub should boot it:

```
insmod part_gpt
search --set --label mypool
linux /ROOT/archlinux@/boot/vmlinuz-linux zfs=mypool rw
initrd /ROOT/archlinux@/boot/initramfs-linux.img
boot
```

You can enter those commands at a `grub>` prompt (press `c` at the Grub menu) or use them as a basis to update your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

- Grub expects a dataset;
- The mount point of your root volume dataset should be `/`;
- your boot files are in `/boot` inside that dataset;
- your initramfs has `HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block keyboard zfs filesystems)`;
- your zpool can have all features enabled (default);
- the location of Grub (same or different disk to the zpool) is irrelevant.

---

*Note that I suffered [significant pain](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447960) trying to list (with `ls`) the contents of `/ROOT/archlinux@/boot` from the Grub prompt. If you try that and get errors then just do what I eventually did: ignore them and just try booting!*