# How to create a ZFS zpool that GRUB can read

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, zfs

The Arch Linux ZFS wiki page explains [grub-compatible pool creation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS#GRUB-compatible_pool_creation), as does [this page about booting Fedora](https://www.csparks.com/BootFedoraZFS), but I have not been able to create a pool that is readable by Grub. The Arch Linux wiki page about [Installing Arch Linux on ZFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_ZFS) highlights certain bugs but doesn't really explain how to overcome them.

The linked pages explain that Grub supports a subset of [zpool features](https://us-east.manta.joyent.com/smartosman/public/man5/zpool-features.5.html) and cannot read a pool that uses features that it doesn't support. They go on to explain how to configure a suitable pool but I have been unable to make it work. The supported feature subset does not appear to be documented anywhere.

I am using a virtual machine to test with Grub 2.02 and Arch Linux kernel 4.16.13-1-ARCH which is the most recent and is compatible with the current `zfs-linux` package version (`zfs-linux-0.7.9.4.16.13.1-1`). I am not (yet) trying to make a bootable system, only to prove that Grub can read the zpool. Here is what I have tried:

First, like the [arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS#GRUB-compatible_pool_creation) suggests, by disabling unwanted features:

```
# zpool create \
    -o feature@multi_vdev_crash_dump=disabled \
    -o feature@large_dnode=disabled           \
    -o feature@sha512=disabled                \
    -o feature@skein=disabled                 \
    -o feature@edonr=disabled                 \
    testpool mirror \
    /dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB{5f2d4170-647f16b7,f38966d8-57bff7df}
```

which results in these features:

```
testpool  feature@async_destroy          enabled                       local
testpool  feature@empty_bpobj            active                        local
testpool  feature@lz4_compress           active                        local
testpool  feature@multi_vdev_crash_dump  disabled                      local
testpool  feature@spacemap_histogram     active                        local
testpool  feature@enabled_txg            active                        local
testpool  feature@hole_birth             active                        local
testpool  feature@extensible_dataset     active                        local
testpool  feature@embedded_data          active                        local
testpool  feature@bookmarks              enabled                       local
testpool  feature@filesystem_limits      enabled                       local
testpool  feature@large_blocks           enabled                       local
testpool  feature@large_dnode            disabled                      local
testpool  feature@sha512                 disabled                      local
testpool  feature@skein                  disabled                      local
testpool  feature@edonr                  disabled                      local
testpool  feature@userobj_accounting     active                        local
```

Then, like the [fedora example](https://www.csparks.com/BootFedoraZFS), by enabling wanted features:

```
zpool create -d \
    -o feature@async_destroy=enabled \
    -o feature@empty_bpobj=enabled \
    -o feature@spacemap_histogram=enabled \
    -o feature@enabled_txg=enabled \
    -o feature@hole_birth=enabled \
    -o feature@bookmarks=enabled \
    -o feature@embedded_data=enabled \
    -o feature@large_blocks=enabled \
    testpool mirror \
    /dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB{5f2d4170-647f16b7,f38966d8-57bff7df}
```

which results in these features:

```
# zpool get all testpool | grep feature
testpool  feature@async_destroy          enabled                       local
testpool  feature@empty_bpobj            active                        local
testpool  feature@lz4_compress           disabled                      local
testpool  feature@multi_vdev_crash_dump  disabled                      local
testpool  feature@spacemap_histogram     active                        local
testpool  feature@enabled_txg            active                        local
testpool  feature@hole_birth             active                        local
testpool  feature@extensible_dataset     enabled                       local
testpool  feature@embedded_data          active                        local
testpool  feature@bookmarks              enabled                       local
testpool  feature@filesystem_limits      disabled                      local
testpool  feature@large_blocks           enabled                       local
testpool  feature@large_dnode            disabled                      local
testpool  feature@sha512                 disabled                      local
testpool  feature@skein                  disabled                      local
testpool  feature@edonr                  disabled                      local
testpool  feature@userobj_accounting     disabled                      local
```

In each case, I loaded some content:

```
# cp -a /boot /testpool
```

And then, rebooted into Grub:

```
grub> search --set --label testpool
grub> ls /
@/
grub> ls /@
error: compression algorithm 80 not supported
.
grub> ls /@/
error: compression algorithm inherit not supported
.
```

I tried enabling/disabling some features, most notably `lz4_compress`. I also tried creating a dataset on the pool. Nothing I tried worked inside Grub.

I expected to be able to list `/boot` or `/@/boot`.

Errors encountered include

- `compression algorithm inherit not supported`
- `compression algorithm 66 not supported`
- `compression algorithm 80 not supported`
- `incorrect dnode type`

**How should a ZFS zpool be created in order for it to be readable by Grub?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grub cannot reliably perform a directory listing of a zpool due to a bug as [confirmed via the mailing list](https://zfsonlinux.topicbox.com/groups/zfs-discuss/T640ad30fb0a65ee6-Mf5f90aeebbcf55f4fb7280df/zfs-discuss-zfs-0-7-9-and-grub-compatibility):

> listing directory contents in Grub is broken, I have a patch lying
> around that fixes that specific issue. if you get strange error messages
> (e.g., something like invalid BP type or compression algorithm), it's
> likely this issue.

This problem is present in Grub installed from ArchLinux and also Fedora 28. Ubuntu, however, appears to have patched their Grub to fix this (confirmed with Ubuntu 16.10).

Grub can, however, read the files required to boot. You can create a zpool that Grub will boot like this:

```
zpool create -m none "$ZPOOL" "$RAIDZ" "${DISKS[@]}"
```

where the variables define the name of the pool, e.g `mypool`, the raid level, e.g. `mirror` and the disks, e.g `/dev/disk/by-id/...` (two disks being required for a mirror).

You need to create a dataset

```
zfs create -p "$ZPOOL"/ROOT/archlinux
```

And you need to set the dataset's mount point:

```
zfs set mountpoint=/ "$ZPOOL"/ROOT/archlinux
```

You can then boot it with Grub using commands like:

```
insmod part_gpt
search --set --label mypool
linux /ROOT/archlinux@/boot/vmlinuz-linux zfs=mypool rw
initrd /ROOT/archlinux@/boot/initramfs-linux.img
boot
```

I [scripted this](https://git.io/fJDPf) to test it in a VirtualBox machine. I installed Arch from the ISO onto a normal ext4 root and then used that to install a new ZFS root onto two mirrored virtual disks. The above is a summary - see the [script](https://git.io/fJDPf) for full details.

Comment: Dunnow how you got this woirking, but on recent centos `grub2-probe /` fails to detect zfs when all of the features are enabled for a pool. It even states the exact feature it stumbles on (and zfs detection fails after that) and then, sure, it cannot boot when asked. This is an interesting post, but all the grub directives you're providing are pretty much regular ones required for a boot from zfs.

Comment: And yeah - from my opinion - this has nothing to do with ability to actually list zpool/zfs contents from grub [rescue shell].

Comment: @drookie my systems work with all listed features showing as either _enabled_ or _active_ (the listed features being those identified in the question). Nothing is disabled. I don't use `grub-probe` though and I hand roll my own `grub.cfg`.

Comment: Could you please show your grub version ?

Comment: Sure, @drookie, my Grub version shows as 2.03 on the Grub screen. I did build it myself from source because I also use these [crypto extensions](http://grub.johnlane.ie), I specifically built from [this tag](https://github.com/johnlane/grub/tree/cryptopatch_v4) (not that that would make any difference to the ZFS support).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's good to know that recent grub version has full zfs support.

Answer (score 1):

> The supported feature subset does not appear to be documented anywhere.

The only reliable place where I could find the list of features supported is GRUB's [source code](https://github.com/rhboot/grub2/blob/29d44a236a5e939b8ff24e6c31141d5b1e48f693/grub-core/fs/zfs/zfs.c#L281) (permalink to today's version). Basically all write-only features plus those explicitly listed there.