# How to create a GRUB entry for a FreeBSD on ZFS installation?

Tags: freebsd, grub2, dual-boot, zfs

To be clear what I want is a FreeBSD GRUB2 entry that boots FreeBSD on a ZFS (name: zroot) with BIOS firmware (not UEFI). The operating system GRUB is installed on is Arch Linux if it helps, Arch is using a ext4 root, it is FreeBSD that is using ZFS.

My partition table is (GPT):

```
/dev/sda1 - BIOS boot (1M) 
/dev/sda2 - Linux swap (4G) 
/dev/sda3 - Linux filesystem (ext4, 50G) 
/dev/sda4 - FreeBSD boot (128k) 
/dev/sda5 - FreeBSD ZFS filesystem (74G)
```

I've seen [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109272/add-freebsd-to-grub2-boot-menu/109278#109278) but it pertains to FreeBSD on a UFS root, and I've also seen [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/450516/27613) which pertains to Arch Linux on ZFS, not FreeBSD on ZFS.

I've tried using this entry:

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" --class freebsd --class bsd --class os {
    insmod zfs
    insmod bsd
    set root=(hd0,4)
    kfreebsd /boot/kernel/kernel
    kfreebsd_loadenv /boot/device.hints
    set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom="zfs:zroot"
    set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom.options=rw
    set kFreeBSD.hw.psm.synaptics_support=1
}
```

but I received this error:

[image]

Using FreeBSD's bootloader (which sadly I overrode by installing GRUB to my disk, although it is simple to restore it) I managed to boot my FreeBSD install, so there's nothing wrong with it. I installed FreeBSD and set it up to boot by following what I put in this directory: https://github.com/fusion809/freebsd-scripts/tree/master/zfs-manual-install.

Comment: If I read your partition table right, you are setting root as `hd0,5`, but your FreeBSD boot partition is `hd0,4`. I’m guessing your kernel is on `hd0,4`.

Comment: Good point mate, after adjusting the partition to be booted to 4 I get a little further, but now I get another error, which I'll add to my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never mind I found the answer thanks to the [FreeBSD forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/grub2-has-no-zfs-support.25164/post-194477). This is what I needed in my grub.cfg:

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" --class freebsd --class bsd --class os {
    insmod zfs
    insmod bsd
    search -s -l zroot
    kfreebsd /@/boot/zfsloader
    kfreebsd_loadenv /@/boot/device.hints
}
```

To be clear I have tried this successfully, I even tried writing a file and rebooting to check it wasn't just read-only and the file was still there and had not been altered by the reboot in any way (not even its permissions were).

Comment: Be sure to check your answer.  You won't get points but this was a good find. +1 vote from me

Comment: I've tried it, I was concerned that maybe omitting the rw line might make things read-only, but I wrote a file rebooted and the file was there and was the same. So from what I can tell it is working perfectly. If you have a specific concern of something I may have overlooked please do tell.